# Wrapping IF ISERROR around INDEX function

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, excel-2003, parentheses

I have a problem with a dynamic list in Excel 2003 where some cells that I want to be empty are returning `#NUM!`. I have tried manipulating the following code, but to no avail:

> =IF(ISERROR(INDEX(venue_name, SMALL(IF(($A$10=date_ns)*(COUNTIF($A$13:A29,venue_name)=0), ROW(date_ns)-MIN(ROW(date_ns))+1, ""), 1)))

I know its something to do with syntax/parentheses but have exhausted myself trying different combinations. Without the `IF(ISERROR(` and the closing bracket, the code runs absolutely fine.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's corrupt or not, but you have unbalanced parens.

Comment: @pnuts Ah, okay, makes sense now ^_^

Comment: are you able to help with the unbalanced parens?

Comment: =INDEX(venue_name, SMALL(IF(($A$10=date_ns)*(COUNTIF($A$13:A14,venue_name)=0), ROW(date_ns)-MIN(ROW(date_ns))+1, ""), 1))

This one works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To use ISERROR you'd have to repeat the whole formula normally but presumably error is caused by an insufficient number of matching criteria so try this version in A14:

**[Revised simpler version]**

`=IF(SUM(($A$10=date_ns)*(COUNTIF($A$13:A13,venue_name)=0)),INDEX(venue_name,MATCH(1,($A$10=date_ns)*(COUNTIF($A$13:A13,venue_name)=0),0)),"")`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied down

....or you can use this version which doesn't need <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$10=date_ns)*(COUNTIF($A$13:A13,venue_name)=0)),INDEX(venue_name,MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$10=date_ns)*(COUNTIF($A$13:A13,venue_name)=0),0),0)),"")`

see sample file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eaqblbp58d9jmz5/list%20matches.xls)

Comment: the above worked in removing the #NUM! but unfortunately it all removed a lot of expected results from the list too.

Comment: OK, apologies - I probably misunderstood slightly, are you putting the formula in A14 and copying down. I'll revise the formula for that scenario

Comment: i am putting the formula in A14 and copying down, yes. Thank you for your help by the way.

Comment: okay so revised formula but it duplicated each result. any suggestions?

Comment: I created a test worksheet and tested both of the suggested formulas - it seems to work OK for me - which of the formulas did you use - did you alter it at all?

Comment: I added a sample file showing the formula working - obviously I had to create some sample data which may look nothing like your real data but should demonstrate the principle

Comment: Apologies Barry, i copied the wrong query in. Could i ask a further favour. 

i have the below query, does much the same thing. however some of the results are skewed by values of 'null' in a list. 

=IF(SUM(($G$10=date_ns)*(COUNTIF($H$14:H14,value_traded_ns)=0)),INDEX(value_traded_ns,MATCH(1,($G$10=date_ns)*(COUNTIF($H$14:H14,value_traded_ns)=0),0)),"")

is there a way to make the above query, skip any value of null and carry on from where it left off? else my data is not coherent. Thank you

Comment: What exactly do you have in the "null" cells, is it a text value of "null", a truly blank cell or a blank "" returned by a formula .....or something else again

Comment: it is a text value of "null" however i can change it to be blank if that is easier. Thanks

Comment: You can add an extra condition in to both the initial SUM and the MATCH function, i.e. `=IF(SUM(($G$10=date_ns)*(COUNTIF($H$14:H14,value_traded_ns)=0)*(value_traded_ns<>"null")),INDEX(value_traded_ns,MATCH(1,($G$10=date_ns)*(COUNTIF($H$14:H14,value_traded_ns)=0)*(value_traded_ns<>"null"),0)),"")`

Comment: Hi Barry, i thought it would be an extra condition somewhere. I have taken your script and although it removes null values it doesnt ignore them and skip to the next line. so the values are out line with the venue names on the left hand side. any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Barry, i have found that the pivot table can create what im looking for here, with regards to removing null from a list and the corresponding venue name. is there a way to make all 'null' values still appear in the list? originally, it only counted the first instance of 'null' and not subsequent instances. sorry if that is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have been superseded by events but considering =ISERROR, as the maestro has said “you’d have to repeat the whole formula normally”. (Not necessary in later versions of Excel that have =IFERROR). Hence:

```
=IF(
ISERROR(
INDEX(venue_name, SMALL(IF(($A$10=date_ns)*(COUNTIF($A$13:A17,venue_name)=0), ROW(date_ns)-MIN(ROW(date_ns))+1, ""), 1))
)
,"",
INDEX(venue_name, SMALL(IF(($A$10=date_ns)*(COUNTIF($A$13:A17,venue_name)=0), ROW(date_ns)-MIN(ROW(date_ns))+1, ""), 1))
)
```

the third and sixth lines (INDEX ...) are the 'working formula'. The first, fifth and last are the =IF condition (where a blank result is assumed to be required if TRUE). The second and fourth lines are the =ISERROR, which returns TRUE if an error is found (as a result of the 'working formula') and FALSE otherwise.

Could be represented as: =IF(error in working formula, blank, working formula).